# how can i serve images urls usign django

Tags: python, django, image, python-2.7

in my django app i can serve images using path like this `src="/media/user/image.png"`using {{ `apps.upload.url` }} but now i want to serve images to html page using urls links likes this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image.png`

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','static_dirs'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','static_root')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static','media')
MEDIA_URL = ('/media/')
```

models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    upload = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
 ..............
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

in html page :

```
<img  src="/media/user_1/image.png" >
```

Comment: Keep `upload = model.ImageField()`, this will directly save your image to `media/`.

Comment: @BidhanMajhi i change my model and don't work again

Comment: I have not noticed it earlier. In your settings.py change your media root to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')` and media root to `'/media/'` .

Comment: @Bidhan Majhi i change that and now working again

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the `user_directory_path` function from the [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) in the Django Docs. This saves each image to a folder based on the `user.id`. You will need to update your `MyModel` and remove the `upload_to` attribute:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    upload = models.ImageField()
```

This should work for any new images you upload.

The example of what you want also includes a fully qualified URL rather than a relative url. If that is what you want, set the `MEDIA_URL` in your [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#media-url) to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/`.

If you have existing images in the system and you want to access them without `user_x` in the path, you will probably need to:

- move images out of their `user_x` folders to the parent folder
- update the value of `MyModel.upload` for each image. If you have many images, a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) might be necessary.

Comment: thanks for response,i follow your details (i change my image field without user_directory_path and i change MEDIA_URL to 127.0.0.1:8000/media and put new image for example) but now dont display image for all browsers,and dont work standalone url 127.0.0.1:8000/media/myimage.png ...any idea why ?

Comment: Check in the media folder of your django project to ensure the image has been uploaded there.

Comment: yeah upload there